# MS-Word string length mismatching result of Python string len() Function and .rstrip Method

Tags: python, ms-word, whitespace, string-length

I'm came across a bit of an anomaly in a python script that i am writing that forced me to test the string `len()` function to check for string lengths. It appears to me that the `len()` function always seems to return the length of the string minus any whitespace characters at the end of the string which would make using `.rstrip` redundant. Is this true?

EDIT: I am reading from an xls document. Looping over rows in a particular column and printing out the len of the strings in each row. I'm starting to think it's a MS com thing. I copied the string from excel into MS Word and even Word is returning the character count minus any white spaces at the end....

Comment: No.  Something else must be the reason.

Comment: Agree with @mgkrebbs. Show some code.

Comment: Are you sure there is whitespace *at the end*?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure. When I click in the cell (double click) the cursor sits one space beyond the end of thes string and in others, it sits right at the end of the last letter. If i physicall count the characters and compare tyo the printout, there are only 2 cases where the cursor sits one space beyond the last character, yet the space doesn't get counted.

Comment: Please show some Python code that reproduces this. Anecdotal accounts about 
what MS-Word does don't help, and don't show any bug in Python. This question should be closed unless code showing a reproducible Python issue is added.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not true, as you can trivially verify.

```
print len("a   ")    # 4
```

Comment: Weird. That works, but I guess I am reading from an xls document. I'm looking through the rows and printing out the character length in each cell from a particular column (general data type) and it prints out the len() of each string in each cell minus any whitespace characters at the end. Maybe it's a com thing? I just copied and pasted the strings into MS Word to check the character count and even word is stripping whitespaces at the end....